# How do I stop jQuery Mobile button group from overflowing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to fit 7 buttons horizontally but am seeing some overflow on the smaller screen sizes.

[Button Group Overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRvtO.png)

```
<div data-mini="true">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2a" id="checkbox-h-2a">
      <label for="checkbox-h-2a">Sun</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2b" id="checkbox-h-2b">
      <label for="checkbox-h-2b">Mon</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2c" id="checkbox-h-2c">
      <label for="checkbox-h-2c">Tue</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2d" id="checkbox-h-2d">
      <label for="checkbox-h-2d">Wed</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2e" id="checkbox-h-2e">
      <label for="checkbox-h-2e">Thu</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2f" id="checkbox-h-2f">
      <label for="checkbox-h-2f">Fri</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2g" id="checkbox-h-2g">
      <label for="checkbox-h-2g">Sat</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Could be a width issue on the div, can you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try set mini version applied directly in the fieldset tag, something like this:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i came across the same requirement some time ago and i found out that is not really easy. This is how i solved it:

Assuming your `<div data-mini="true">` has a class: `<div data-mini="true" class="no-wrap">` :

```
.no-wrap {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.no-wrap .ui-controlgroup-controls {
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 100%;
}

.no-wrap .ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-checkbox {
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  width: 14%; // <- 100% / num. of controls
}

.no-wrap .ui-btn {
  text-overflow: initial !important;
}

.no-wrap label.ui-btn {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Explanation: the width of each control shall be set in percent as 100 / num. of controls in your `controlgroup`. For example, if you need:

- 8 controls: width: 12.5%
- 7 controls: width: 14.2%

... and so on.

By adding the container `div` you can also specify the width of the whole `controlgroup` inside the JQM page:

```
.no-wrap .ui-controlgroup-controls {
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 80%; // <- this will set the width of the whole controlgroup
}
```

> DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/fFU7Zf5Wr2jD6anD9h4L?p=preview

Maybe it seems a little bit overcooked, but the reason is to keep things cross-browser, also in IE.